# How to indent STX transformation output(type "XML")?

Tags: transformation, stx

How to indent the output XML that is generated as a result of STX transformation. I searched for it in the official documentation by looking at the **transform** element, but found that it does not have any indent attribute, like XSLT has. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use xmllint, for example

```
xmllint --format file.xml > file-formated.xml
```